# verifying website as a business for facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for ideas on how to else to demonstrate that my website is associated with my business as part of verification for my application.

Things that i have tried already and had a perception that nobody have read them:
1. domain is registered under my business name and is visible on whois
2. domain verification is passed as part of Brand Safety -> Domains -> verification (uploaded the requested file). The domain is showing under Business manager as OWNED domains
3. presented an invoice where the domain is listed as part of the "Billed to" section together with my business name.

The Facebook email suggests verification by phone, but this option is not present when i go to "upload documents" link - I am in Australia and it looks like we are not "reachable" (????).

My application is continuously returned with exactly the same reason:
1.we recommend you return to business verification and choose to confirm by phone instead. - there is NO such option there, only confirm by email. Do I need to "switch" anything to enable this???

2. "Upload a document showing the business owns the email domain you entered — Make sure it shows both the business' legal name AND the domain. " - the invoice to the domain AND business from the domain registrar shows this very clearly but was rejected.

Any ideas on what else to try?

Comment: I see that it was asked in May, if you managed to find a solution could you share it?

Comment: yes, i got approval shortly after. I will put a blog post tomorrow explaining the "journey" and post the link. In short, they wanted personal info on the website ON TOP of all documents provided

Comment: It will be very helpful, thanks. Your blog has to be on the first google search results page, because there is nothing useful on internet for that problem

Comment: Hi, I added a page to my website that show the business email, address, phone num., and my name - I sent them a screenshot of it, and they still say email domain is not verified. Is that what you did?

Comment: @EvgenyBenediktov I also sent a screenshot to them, but they still say the same.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution? we are all waiting for that, thank you.